# Select the first option of SelectInput by default in admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

I've got a `SelectInput` with two choices:

```
<SelectInput source="existing_user" choices={[
        { id: 'existing', name: 'Existing'},
        { id: 'new', name: 'New User' },
  ]} validate={required} />
```

I also have a `DependInput` component that renders other fields, depending on the value of `existing_user`. **I would like the first option ('existing') to be selected by default**. However the `SelectInput` field is always empty when the form loads, so no other fields are visible:
[image]

I tried setting the underlying `SelectField`'s `value` property to 'existing' through `options`, but then I'm unable to edit the `SelectInput` (clicking the second option does nothing).

I'm probably missing something simple since this should be elementary, but I couldn't find anything helpful in the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#selectinput) about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `defaultValue` either on the `SelectInput` or on the form containing it should do the trick:

- https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html
- https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CreateEdit.html#default-values

Comment: Simple indeed, don't know how I missed it. Thank you.